# Create cursor loader from two datasources?

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a method that queries a database table via a provider and returns a `CursorLoader` to be used to populate a UI via a `CursorAdapter`.
I need in one particular case only to add some extra data that are not part of the database result set.
Is there a way to somehow for that case add some extra "fake" rows with the data?
Like creating a cursor loader from two data sources?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) to add some "fake" rows. Then merge the two cursors (CursorAdapter, MatrixCursor) using the [MergeCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) class. MergeCursor will present the two Cursors as a single linear Cursor.

Comment: So in one place: i) Do the SQL query and create cursor loader-1 ii) Fetch the other data iii) Create MatrixCursor iv) Add data from (ii) and v) Create MergeCursor from these 2 right? Anything to watch out?

Comment: Just be careful of the columns your MatrixCursor will has (number of, names etc). The two original cursors (CursorAdapter, MatrixCursor) can have the same number of columns or a different. The decision is up to you.
Other than that, nothing to watch out for.