# Create cursor loader for data directory

Tags: android, uri, android-cursorloader

I've implemented [photo basics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) to request a camera action and save the photo to my data directory:

```
storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[package]/files/Pictures/[image name]
```

I now want to be able to retrieve all the images, and I'd like to do so by using a CursorLoader.

Previously, creating a CursorLoader for all external media files would be like so:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED};
return new CursorLoader(this,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns,
        null,
        null,
        //Sort by descending date
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC");
```

I would like to do this but also include the images in my private data folder. Is there any way around this?

I'm not sure how to retrieve a content URI for that folder (only file://). Another solution is to somehow make this folder visible to the media scanner as detailed under "Add the Photo to a Gallery" in the photo basics. Doing this didn't seem to change anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.

**Solution 1.** Get a list of the private data folder images e.g. by using the [File.listFiles()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) method and create a custom "fake" cursor using the [MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html). Then, you add the private images as rows of the "fake" cursor. Finally, use a [MergeCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) to merge the two cursors (the one you already have to your question and the "fake" one) to a single one.

**Solution 2.** The second solution is pretty similar to the first one. Instead of getting a list of the files, you can [create a Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) and query it. Then, as above, you can use a MergeCursor to merge the two resulting cursors to a single one.

I leave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109797/6569284) here for reference.

Comment: I just rebooted to check out solution 1 and I can neither see the images in my cursor nor in a gallery app. I'm not sure if there is anything extra I need to do to make those images visible from the app data folder. I'm adding the images to an adapter and I was hoping to avoid solutions like MatrixCursor. If that is the case I may just consider adding the items directly to the adapter in front of the other cursor items

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to change the target directory, I was using the Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES. So there is nothing you can do to make these images available to the Media Provider. I'll update my answer. If you use a CursorAdapter then I believe that you should use the MatrixCursor/MergeCursor solution as it's not difficult to implement it.

Comment: Does `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` show pictures from all folders in the sd card? Ultimately that's my goal so if that's the fix that's great. I'll try it later and comment if you haven't replied yet.

Comment: I was calling the `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` which points to the public external storage, its files are public and the [Save the Full-size Photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) paragraph suggests to use. But in your case, your images have been stored to the private folder which is returned from the `Context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` and unfortunately they are not accessible.

Comment: nice catch! I didn't even notice that. I just looked at their sample code which used `getExternalFilesDir`. I've accepted your answer